# Using PATCH method in html form

Tags: html, forms

How to use PATCH method in an html form to send data to a server?
I've already done this
***Html***

```
<form class="type-title"  method="POST" id="alter">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH"/>
        <input id="alter" type="text" name="alter"/>
        <button onclick="alter_name();">update</button>
</form>
```

***JS***

```
function alter_name(){
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/member", {
        method: 'PATCH',
        headers: {
            'Content-type' :'application/json'
        },
        body: {
            "name":alter_name.value.toString()
            } 
    }),then((response) =>{
        return response.json();
    }).then((data) =>{
        console.log(data);
    })
}
```

but it still not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is how you have addressed the *input* value. Your form's id: `id="alter"` is the same name as the input which is invalid, but in your script you are not referencing this field correctly at all, lets fix all this...

Firstly with the HTML form, do not post back as that might affect other workflows on the form. We do this by forcing the button to act as a simple standalone HTML Button instead of being the *submit* button for the form. Do this by setting the `type` attribute of the button to `"button"`:
_I've also changed the Id of the form to be unique and removed the `_method` hidden input.

```html
<form class="type-title" id="alter_form">
    <input id="alter" type="text" name="alter"/>
    <button onclick="alter_name();" type="button">update</button>
</form>
```

- You were on the right track with using javascript and `fetch()` to send the data as your API is not likely to be setup to accept *form-data* if you are using `PATCH` as the *method* on a standard form submit.

The other fix is in the script itself, we need to deliberately *stringify* the object payload that we sent in the body, this way we can control or enforce the serialization instead of relying on javascript, we can also more easily inspect the contents when or if it goes wrong.

- Notice how the field is referenced using the path `formId.fieldId.value`

The other issue you had was that your JSON object wasn't formed correctly, you had quotes around the property name, which would have resulted in quotes being escaped and encoded into the JSON string value, which we don't want.

Finally, I've specified the encoding in the `Content-Type` as it was required on my system to parse the content on the server side.

```js
function alter_name(){
    
    let content = {
            Details: alter_form.alter.value.toString()
            };

    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/member", {
        method: 'PATCH',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(content)
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log('PATCH Response.status: ', response.status);
        if(response.status !== 204)
            return response.json();
        else
            return response.statusText;
    }).then((data) => {
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

For a few bonus points, I've added some handling for a `204: No Content` response from the server. Many `PATCH` implementations do not return content unless you explicitly request it with a `Prefer` HTML Header.

Comment: thank you. you give me a really big help